# Delay an application at /etc/xdg/startup

Tags: startup, guake, xdg

For some reason when it's started too quickly when it's active it shows my desktop instead of overlaying on the active windows.I have `guake.desktop` in `/etc/xdg/startup` and I'm wondering if there's a way to delay it's startup by a few seconds?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Guake Terminal
Name[pt]=Guake Terminal
Name[pt_BR]=Guake Terminal
Comment=Use the command line in a Quake-like terminal
Comment[pt]=Utilizar a linha de comando em um terminal estilo Quake
Comment[pt_BR]=Utilizar a linha de comando em um terminal estilo Quake
TryExec=guake
Exec=guake
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/guake/guake.png
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically to delay a .desktop that is autostarted you'd add a line like this, example here of 4 sec's

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=4
```

Just to note, the .desktop you posted above has `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` so it shouldn't be autostarting quake. It it is truly set to false & guake is autostarting then look in `~/.config/autostart/` for another .desktop for quake to add above line to.

Comment: Only `google-chrome.desktop` is there :( BTW, I'm using openbox. I checked `~/.config/openbox/autostart` but guake is not there as well.

Comment: Try enabling the one in `/etc/xdg/startup` & give it a delay line. Otherwise myself don't know openbox